# Div aligning issue in a blogspot template

Tags: css, html, blogspot

I would really appreciate if someone can have a look at [hindilyricsall.blogspot.com](http://hindilyricsall.blogspot.com) and can find out why the next arrow in the carousel below the navbar is not aligned and is shifted below the carousel?
Related code:

```
<div id='carousel'>
<div id='previous_button'/>
<div class='container'>
<script>
document.write(&quot; &lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default?max-results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
</script>   
</div>
  <div id='next_button'/>
  <div style='clear:both;'/>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#carousel{width:100%;height:240px;position:relative;display:block;}
#carousel .container{position:relative;left:25px;margin-right:25px;width:930px;height:240px;overflow:hidden}
#carousel #previous_button{position:absolute;width:25px;height:240px;background:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SFH7pfuPOg4/UAVZimY-OuI/AAAAAAAAHqE/MOKZ4nE0EFM/s1600/prev.png) center;z-index:100;cursor:pointer;}
#carousel #next_button{position:absolute;right:0;width:25px;height:240px;background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pFR58sZNzCo/UAVZh9I72lI/AAAAAAAAHp8/JTIiHJfsqHA/s1600/next.png) center;z-index:100;cursor:pointer;}
#carousel #next_button:hover,#carousel #previous_button:hover{filter:alpha(opacity=70);opacity:.7}
#carousel ul li:hover{background:#111}
#carousel ul{width:100000px;position:relative;margin-top:10px}
#carousel ul li{background:#272727;display:inline;float:left;text-align:center;font:12px Oswald;line-height:1.3em;width:130px;height:200px;margin:0 1px 6px 9px;padding:8px 5px 6px;border:1px solid #323232;-moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;}
#carousel ul li a.slider_title{color:#ccc;display:block;margin-top:6px}
#carousel ul li a.slider_title:hover{color:#fec700}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this code to your css file

```
#carousel .container {
    float:left;
}
```

The arrow will be aligned with the caroussel

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with HTML structuring but by adding float:left to .container should fix your problem

Arrow is coming on next line as div is block level element and takes entire space.

```
.container {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what are the issues with html structuring?

Comment: .carousel is relative positioned so by placing arrows and container absolutely you could achieve solution Or you can go for float approach where you are floating these elements to left.

Comment: Yup and inline JS and inline styling is also used. Its good if you can decouple them and keep separately in file.

Comment: This is a blogger template. We cannot use a separate file.